# py2neo socket error - windows

Tags: python, neo4j, py2neo

Currently getting the following error using windows to ingest data into Neo4j:

```
py2neo.packages.httpstream.http.SocketError: unknown error
```

I have a working example ingesting maybe 100 rows of a csv but the code breaks with the error as reported above when I load a much larger dataset (100,000 rows). No other change in the code other than data size.

Anyone else had a similar problem?

Answer (score 2):

Solved.

For me, this was a problem with Neo4j versions.

I changed to using Neo4j 1.9 (i.e. not 2.0, as I was using) and the code ran as expected. Not the best solution though if you need to run Neo4j 2.0

Louis